# What are the exit status codes for the G-WAN executable?

Tags: g-wan

I'm trying to serve a big number of small files with G-WAN (version 4.3.14, started with sudo on 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.3). I start hammering it with requests over a single connection using wget to provide base URL and a file with a list of the URL suffixes. At some point, which is different for different runs, the gwan executable silently exits. There's no trace in the gwan log or in the site error log (I did change '_log' to 'log' to enable logging). The exit status code is 139. What does it mean? When I stop it with Ctrl-C the exit code is 130.

Is there a reference for the exit status codes? I cannot find any with Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Ubuntu 14.04.3` is very recent while `G-WAN v4.3.14` is very old. Almost every new OS release introduces cincompatibilities that require patches and this is why we have to issue more recent releases for registered users. This explains the 'silent exits' that you are experiencing.

Second, process exits codes can be found this way:

```
./gwan -h
echo $?
0
```

Zero means no error, and any other value is an error ([mixing system flags](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) to be as informative as possible). That's why Ctrl+C returns 130: Control-C is fatal error signal 2, (130 = 128 + 2).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So according to your link 139 means SIGSEGV (128 + 11), i.e. it's a crash. Acting on your suggestion that 14.04 is too new, I also tried it in a root-jailed Ubuntu 12.04 but, obviously, running the 14.04 kernel (3.13.0-62), which I guess is what matters because it crashes again. If I have enough time I'll install 12.04 native and see how it fares there.

Comment: Are You running this system on VM? This might be a problem

Comment: I run native, not in a VM. That's why it was easier for me to spin a root jail than a new VM. But anyway, I later tried with native Ubuntu 12.04.5 and it crashes there too. Thanks everyone for your help. I'll mark the question as answered because it was about the exit status codes, not for the crash.